# Проверить на PHP введенное число на соответствие 1, 10, 100, ..., 10 000 000

Tags: php

Как математически проверить пользовательский ввод: соответствует ли число одному из заданной последовательности: 1, 10, 100, ..., 10 000 000 на PHP. Проверить с помощью preg_match() - не проблема, но как-то не правильно проверять числа функцией, предназначенной для проверки строк.

```
if (!preg_match('/^10{0,7}$/', $_GET['insert_number'])) {
    echo 'число должно быть 1, 10, 100, 1000 и т.д.';
}
```

Как назвать последовательность чисел 1, 10, ..., чтобы сообщение об ошибке было более информативным?

Comment: "число должно представлять собой целую неотрицательную степень десяти" (еще хуже получилось). Проверить же можно через логарифм, посмотрев, насколько он близок к целому числу, или путем анализа остатков от деления на 10 нацело.

Comment: «как-то не правильно» – как-то не правильно. Решение должно проходить набор тестов, быть быстрым и нетребовательным к ресурсам. К тому же пользовательский ввод – это именно строка.

Comment: Проверка preg_match будет быстрее и проще подсчета разных логарифмов

Comment: "Через /^10{0,7}$/ не пройдёт "1"" - успешно проходит, проверено.

Comment: Вы правы, писал до кофе )

Answer (score 5):

Всего 8 вариантов, отчего бы не захардкодить? =)

```
in_array($userInput, [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000]);
```

Ещё странный вариант: смотреть на валидные числа как на **двоичные** – там ведь только единицы и нули допустимы, длиной не более байта (8 позиций).

```
function is10x($userInput) {
    $input = trim($userInput); // убрать пробелы по краям и считать строкой
    $binStr = sprintf('%b', intval($input,2)); // перевести в двоичное число и в строку единиц и нулей
    if( $binStr !== $input) return FALSE; // должно пережить двойной перевод без потерь
    return array_sum(str_split($binStr)) === 1; // должно содержать только одну 1
}
```

[Тесты](http://ideone.com/oBZxgt)

Сообщение: «Число должно начинаться с единицы и, кроме неё, может содержать только нули»

Comment: Вот только хардкорить не нужно :)

Comment: @Miron обоснуйте

Comment: В варианте с preg_match и так хардкор, но изменить диапазон там проще

Comment: движок регулярных выражений, возможно, требует выполнения гораздо большего числа операций, чем поиск в массиве из 8 элементов, не находите?

Comment: Следуя Вашей логике код php-скрипта нужно писать без переводов строк и пробелов - так будет потреблять меньше ресурсов, но ведь это же не удобно, а экономия "на спичках" ? :) Это я к тому, что и мой и Ваш вариант имеют право на жизнь, только Ваш вариант редактировать дольше, в случае изменения условия.

Comment: Годятся все варианты, которые работают. Хорошо разобраться в плюсах и минусах каждого, что мы и сделали : )

Answer (score 3):

Можно проверить через логарифм, но при этом нужно учитывать что функции `log()` и `log10()` всегда возвращают число типа `float`. Можно применить такой хак:

```
$y = 10;
$x = pow((string)log10($y),1);
```

результат работы `log10()` перегоняем в строку и скармливаем функции `pow()`, которая выдает `int` или `float` в зависимости от полученного результата

```
if (is_float($x) || $y < 1)
echo "Число не удовлетворяет условию";

var_dump($x);
```

Answer (score 3):

Написал на Java, т.к не пользуюсь PHP

```
//Проверка на то, является ли число одной из степеней 10: 
public boolean is10(int n) {
    if(n==1) return true;
    else if(n<1) return false;
    return n%10==0 && is10(n/10);
}
```

Ну и попытался конвертировать на PHP:

```
function is10($n): boolean {
    if ($n == 1) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($n < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return $n % 10 == 0 && is10($n / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

нельзя ли сделать простым циклом? так как максимальное число 10 000 000

```
// Функция проверки цисла
function proveritChislo($number){
  // Если число больше 1 можно работать
  while ( $number > 1 ) {
    // Если не заканчивается на 0, значит не правильно
    $ostatok = $number % 10;
    if ($ostatok != 0) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    // убираем последний 0
    $number = ($number - $ostatok) / 10;
  }
  return $number == 1;
}
```

Comment: Можно: `in_array($number, [1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000]);`

Comment: @Sergiks согласен,  так быстрее. Так как компьютеры используются не только для вычисления но и для хранения данных!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$test="1".str_repeat("0",strlen($input)-1);
if($test % $unput != 0) echo "Ошибка бла-бла-бла";
```